# Algorithm to generate random order of elements

Tags: algorithm, random

How to randomize order of approximately 20 elements with lowest complexity? (generating random permutations)

Comment: What do you mean by cca?

Comment: Canonical correlation analysis?

Comment: more about this http://www.freebase.com/view/en/circa

Comment: *ca.* and *cca.* are both abbreviations for *circa*, although *circa* is only used to refer to dates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circa

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a list shuffle question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Knuth's shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle) is a good choice.

Comment: Well I am disappointed that that is the answer. Since you have to first iterate through the list to fill it and then shuffle it (with an admittedly good algorithm), I would have thought that there was a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Some months ago I blogged about obtaining a random permutation of a list of integers.
You could use that as a permutation of indexes of the set containing your elements, and then you have what you want.

- [**Generating random int list in F#**](http://brunoreis.com/tech/generate-random-int-list/)
- [**Uniformly distributed random list permutation in F#**](http://brunoreis.com/tech/uniformly-distributed-random-list-permutation/)

In the first post I explore some possibilities, and finally I obtain "a function to randomly permutate a generic list with O(n) complexity", properly encapsulated to work on immutable data (ie, it is side-effect free).

In the second post, I make it uniformely distributed.

The code is in F#, I hope you don't mind!

Good luck.

**EDIT:** I don't have a formal proof, but intuition tells me that the complexity of such an algorithm cannot be lower than **O(n)**. I'd really appreciate seeing it done faster!

Comment: All permutations must be possible, and re-arranging an array into a derangement (that is, a permutation `p` for which `p(k) != k` for all `k`) requires that every element be visited. Hence O(n) worst case. Or is that still not formal enough?

Comment: Also O(n) average case by the same proof, come to think of it, since IIRC the proportion of permutations of (1...n) which are derangements approaches 1/e as n approaches infinity.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to randomise the order is to make a new list of the correct size (20 in your case), iterate over the first list, and add each element in a random position to the second list. If the random position is already filled, put it in the next free position.

I think this pseudocode is correct:

```
list newList
foreach (element in firstList)
    int position = Random.Int(0, firstList.Length - 1)
    while (newList[position] != null)
        position = (position + 1) % firstList.Length
    newList[position] = element
```

EDIT: so it turns out that this answer isn't actually that good. It is neither particularly fast, nor particularly random. Thankyou for your comments. For a good answer, please scroll back to the top of the page :-)

Comment: In the worst case this algorithm is O(n^2) (ie, if your random number generator says "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...", I let you calculate the rest), not very optimized.

Comment: Putting items in the next free position makes it less random. The items will keep their original order more than in a truly random shuffle. To fix that you would have to pick a new random position when a position is taken, which of course makes it a lot slower.

Comment: That's a good point Guffa. I'd never realised that. Thanks. At least I've learnt something here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably someone already implemented the shuffling for you. For example, in Python you can use [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle), in C++ [`random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/), and in PHP [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

Comment: Surprisingly, in PHP it is called `shuffle` :) I'll update my answer.