# Randomizing elements of the List<>

Tags: c#, .net, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Randomize a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Let's suppose that I have

```
List<SomeClass> _myList;
```

and I populate _myList with ordered collection of objects.  Now, I would like to shuffle them.  How?

I was thinking of using

```
_myList.Sort( (a,b) => r.GetNext() - 0.5 );
```

but I suppose that can work only on SOME implementations of `Sort()`.

BTW, `r = new Random();`

BTW2, my lists are thousands elements large...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c-sharp

Comment: I think you need [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/c-is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm

Answer (score 3):

```
_myList.OrderBy(item => r.Next());
```

Should return you the list's items in random order.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor, nope but I that that should do it

Comment: It's `r.Next()` by the way...

Comment: @Yannick, true, I've fixed the code (un bete copier/coller...)

Comment: This does work, but keep in mind, it does not change the order of the existing list, it only returns a new sequence randomly ordered.

Answer (score 0):

u look some thing like this.

```
private List<E> ShuffleList<E>(List<E> inputList)
{
     List<E> randomList = new List<E>();

     Random r = new Random();
     int randomIndex = 0;
     while (inputList.Count > 0)
     {
          randomIndex = r.Next(0, inputList.Count); //Choose a random object in the list
          randomList.Add(inputList[randomIndex]); //add it to the new, random list
          inputList.RemoveAt(randomIndex); //remove to avoid duplicates
     }

     return randomList; //return the new random list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, extend IList in a (hopefully) efficient way.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    var choices = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count).ToList();
    var rng = new Random();
    for(int n = choices.Count; n > 1; n--)
    {
        int k = rng.Next(n);
        yield return list[choices[k]];
        choices.RemoveAt(k);
    }
    yield return list[choices[0]];
}
```