# Update a part of the UI on Flutter

Tags: flutter

To update the whole widget is easy, we call `SetState()` and we do our changes but what happens if I don't need to update everything?

I have this UI:
[image]

When I load that page I get my array of elements from my app provider:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   var elements = shuffle(Provider.of<GameSettings>(context).set.elements);
```

(took it from this answer: [List.shuffle() in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554129/list-shuffle-in-dart))

I need the `context` to get my saved list of elements, that's why I put it there.

I also have the progress bar which I need to refresh:

```
void _startTimer() {
    var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
    sub.onData((duration) {
      setState(() {
        _current = _start + duration.elapsed.inSeconds;
      });
    });

    sub.onDone(() {
      sub.cancel();
    });
  }
}
```

But when I refresh it, I'm also refreshing my element. This is happening because the whole widget is being called and so my `shuffle` function.

I tried moving the progress button to a different widget, but still the same. How could I just refresh this progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use StatefulBuilder()

your code will be :

```
void _startTimer() {
    StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, setState){
           var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
           sub.onData((duration) {
              setState(() {
                   _current = _start + duration.elapsed.inSeconds;
                });
            });

            sub.onDone(() {
             sub.cancel();
            });
         }
     )

 }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why I need to return a widget? I just need to modify the state with the `_current` value? Sorry if my questions sounds silly, I'm not that familiar with Flutter

Comment: you can modify `_current` value without `setState()` fine , but the Ui of your page doesn't know that `current` is changed .. to solve that you can use `StatefulWidget` and refresh All of the page , but if you want to refresh only a part of your page then you could use 'StatefulBuilder()' in your 'StatelessWidget class' .
in your case you can put only the widget you want to refresh it when `_current` change ..

Comment: Am I wrong with this? StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, setState) { int counter = 0; return Column( children: <Widget>[ RaisedButton( onPressed: () { setState(() { counter++; print(counter); }); }, child: Text( "Increment counter"),), Text("Counter is " + counter.toString()), ], ); }),

Comment: On this case `counter` is always but also, the `Text()` only displays `0`

Comment: got it again: had to move `counter` outside `StatefulBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `StreamController` and `StreamBuilder` widget for that

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: but I already have the list of elements, that's local. I don't have any future or stream. I just need to change is order and elements