# How to shuffling the order of a list from snapshot.docs from Stream in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

this is my code to retrieve user data from firestore:

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Consultant').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 60),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length, 
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
```

there is a possibility to randomize the order of the list casual?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List.shuffle() in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554129/list-shuffle-in-dart)