# In flutter / Dart : how to randomly select a number of items in a list?

Tags: dart

I have a list of n integers. I would like to randomly select three values out of this list and affect them to a three item list.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do get a random element from a List in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart)

Comment: In a way... I read this post. But I have problem to create the second list with the three elements in it... three elements taken randomly in the first list...

Comment: [Shuffle the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48703094/) and select the first three items.

Comment: use [sample](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/sample.html) - the docs say: *"Selects count elements at random from this iterable.

The returned list contains count different elements of the iterable. If the iterable contains fewer that count elements, the result will contain all of them, but will be shorter than count. If the same value occurs more than once in the iterable, it can also occur more than once in the chosen elements."*

Comment: Here you can try this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554129/list-shuffle-in-dart Hope so you can shuffle with this.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a subset of three elements taken from a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create this method:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

List<int> getList(int n, List<int> source) => source.sample(n);
```

**Usage:**

```dart
final outputList = getList(3, your_int_list);
print(outputList); // Prints non-repeating 3 random number
```

Comment: Sorry, is it not a subset of three elements taken from the given list `source`, right?

Comment: @MoneySetsYouFree Yes, it is. Isn't that what OP is asking for?

Comment: he wants a subset of non repeating values, your solution from `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` can produce `[1,1,2]` for example

Comment: @pskink Sorry! I misunderstood it. Although I updated the post.

Comment: no need to reinvent the wheel: [sample](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/sample.html)

Comment: @pskink Haha, right. But I hardly use packages. Can you tell me in `collection` package which `Iterable` or `List` should be apt for this case?

Comment: sorry, what you mean by that? you simply import 'package:collection/collection.dart', that's it

Comment: @pskink Ahh got that. I forgot it's an extension available on all `Iterables`.

Comment: @pskink I updated the code, let me know if there's something wrong in it. Thanks for the `sample` link!

Comment: and the big plus is that package comes with flutter by default so you don't need to do anything

Comment: @pskink I actually put `collection:any` and looking for the corresponding `ListView` haha. You're right this is such an amazing addition. I only heard about it but never tried it on my own. Thanks to you :)

Comment: seems you don't like simple things ;-) all you need is: `source.sample(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this exemple with List of String :

```
import "dart:math";

List<String> list = ['tata','toto','titi','tutu','lala','lolo','lili'];

final random= new Random();

String item= list[random.nextInt(list.length)];
print(item);
```

Comment: This works. But I need to get three different items and put them into another list. Have been trying the "shuffle" method.

Answer (score 0):

With this code select three items from testList1 and add to another list(testList2), but this code sometimes selects the same items. Here is code:

```
    void getRandomItem(){
    T getRandomElement<T>(List<T> testList1) {
      final random = new Random();
      var i = random.nextInt(testList1.length);
      return testList1[i];
    }
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
      var randomItem= getRandomElement(testList1);
      print(randomItem);
      testList2.add(randomItem);
      print(testList2);
    }

  }
```

button event:

```
 onPressed: () {
        getRandomItem();
          },
```