# Random position for widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to put objects randomly, then on new screen I want player to put widgets as before. How can I do that?

What widgets/ packages would make it easy?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a list of objects in your widget, that is displayed in order by the `build` function.

You could use `initState` to shuffle your list the first time your widget loads, using a shuffle function such as [the one provided in this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13556240/15469537).

```dart
List<MyItem> items = [MyItem('first'), MyItem('second'), MyItem('third')];

@override
initState() {
  items = shuffle(items);
  super.initState();
}
```

Then when going to the next screen, you can pass the shuffled version of `items`, and use that as the 'correct' solution.

It's a bit difficult to see what exactly you're looking for as no code was provided, but hopefully this gives you some inspiration for your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **CustomPainter** and Canvas
so can access Offset