# How to randomize Between 3 different groups of photos?

Tags: c#, forms, random, picturebox

I have a Major problem. can't think of a solution. Please help...

I have a Form with a pictureBox in it.

In my solution Resource folder, I've saved 3 different folders(a,b,c).
Each folder contains 3 different photos.

**Every 10Sec**, I will show in the pictureBox, **random Photo from a random folder**.

It must be no repeat's with the photos. Once photo as be selected and shown in the pictureBox, it wont appear again.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried? What is your error code? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you'll get a repeat (or nothing) after 90 seconds, as you have only 9 photos changing every ten seconds...

That being said, you could just load all of your photos (or the information such as the name/location) into a collection up front, then [sort it randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c-sharp).  At that point, just show the images in order.

Comment: Hey Reed, well, my problem is a bit difficult: 1. i need to randomize the photos from each folders as i said above. 2. I'm giving to the viewer the choice to grade each photo. 3. the grade will be saved in a .CSV file along with other data. And now, Here is the catch: the Photo's are shown randomly, but saved as organized in the .CSV file. For Example of <folder, photo, grade, viewer number> : if I'll show  <c,3,5,1>, <c,1,5,2>, <a,1,5,1>, <b,2,5,2>. in the CSV file it will be saved as: <c,3,5,1>,<a,1,5,1> -> next line -> <c,1,5,2>,<b,2,5,2>. Any Suggestions?

Comment: @RoyDoron Keep a class with all of the info you need, and store that in the list, then shuffle the list.  You could then reorder via LINQ as needed on export/save.