# Prevent duplicates in random number with button c#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

My app is written in c#. When you click a button (next) the two images will be changed randomly.  How could I prevent duplicated images?

```
   Random randomclass = new Random();

            int RN = randomclass.Next(0, RL + 1);

                Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.folder.Array[RN].img1");
                Image Aimg = Image.FromStream(myStream);
                pictureBox8.Image = Aimg;
                Stream myStream1 = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.folder.Array[RN].img2");
                Image Dimg = Image.FromStream(myStream1);
                pictureBox4.Image = Dimg;

            h = lessons[RN];
            lessons[RN] = lessons[RL];
            lessons[RL] = h;
          RL-- ;
```

Comment: There's basically two approaches - either you can keep track of the images you've already been to, or you can randomly sort an array of indices, and use these in a sequence.

Comment: mainly i have 10 pics and the user able to press 10th and one click next the two pics will appear and both stored in one index the gist i only want the random number to appear uniquely  through the 10th press

Answer (score 1):

the best thing you can do as luaan suggest in the comments you could simply shuffle an array.
place your images (or the reference to them) in an array/list and use the code below, which I've copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c-sharp), to randomly shuffle the images.

```
static Random random = new Random();

public static IEnumerable<T> RandomPermutation<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    T[] retArray = sequence.ToArray();


    for (int i = 0; i < retArray.Length - 1; i += 1)
    {
        int swapIndex = random.Next(i, retArray.Length);
        if (swapIndex != i) {
            T temp = retArray[i];
            retArray[i] = retArray[swapIndex];
            retArray[swapIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

    return retArray;
}
```

once you've shuffled the array simply loop trough it, evry images in the array will be displayed once in a random way.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an array (or similar data structure) of previously used images and re-generate your random number / image if it's been used before? If it's a web application, you'd probably also want to store it in the ViewState or SessionState so it could be unique between users and have a way to reset itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't formatted that well and it's not really clear what you want, but if your actual question is "how to generate two unique, random numbers?", try something like this:

```
var random = new Random();

int number1 = random.Next(0, RL + 1);
int number2 = number1;

while (number2 == number1)
{
    number2 = random.Next(0, RL + 1);
}
```

If you don't want to show any of the two images shown any next time, see Luaan's comment or Drew's answer.