# Shuffle Numbers and Generate Same Sequence of Numbers in every Execution

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Below snippet shuffle numbers And changes sequence of numbers in every execution:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
```

BUT I want shuffle numbers and generate a same sequence of numbers in every execution of application?

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of randomly arranging the numbers?

Comment: Generate them once and hard-code the result. Or just use `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToArray()`. That's a plausible, albeit unlikely, random ordering.

Comment: Don't use GUIDs to shuffle. Use a `Random` object for shuffling and initialize the object with the same seed.

Comment: You can generate a new `Random` class object and initialize it with a hard-coded seed value. Doing this will guarantee the same random numbers each execution. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is more efficient to use an algorithm like [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to reorder the items. The run-time complexity of `OrderBy` is `O(N log N)` while Fisher-Yates shuffle is `O(N)`.

Also, to provide random numbers you should use the `Random` class, not `Guid.NewGuid` which serves a completely different purpose and just happens to create something that is random (at a higher cost).

I prefer to implement the shuffle as an extension method:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, Random random)
    {
        for (var i = list.Count; i > 1; i -= 1)
        {
            var j = random.Next(i); 
            var temp = list[j];
            list[j] = list[i - 1];
            list[i - 1] = temp;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

You can achieve the desired result by providing a `Random` instance with a specific seed (in this case 0). This will ensure that the sequence of random numbers generated are the same each time the code executes:

```
var shuffledList = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToList().Shuffle(new Random(0));
```

Comment: Nice! I swear I have this exact same code in my little extensions library.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an O(n log n) sort to shuffle (never mind the overhead of generating the `Guid` values), you should use `Random` and the standard O(n) [Fisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net/)-[Yates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c-sharp/) [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt). Then you can give the `Random` object the same seed with every execution.