# generate one of the mutiple possibles anagrams of a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm kind of new to JavaSCript and I want to ask wow can I make a random anagram generator, without a list of all possible anagrams (because that's not optimized)

Example:

**input**: "abc"

**output**: get the input, split it (["a", "b", "c"]), randomize the split and join them (["cba"])

This is for a command for my bot in Discord.

I've searched about this, but I just found generators for all anagrams possible in the same string.

Thank you for reading this, have a nice day

Comment: You've already come up with the solution, how would you execute it by hand, on a paper?

Comment: get all possible and randomly select one?

Comment: the thing is i dont know how can i put this in the code

Comment: no, pick the input and transform in just one anagram without try every single possible anagram of the same

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array ?

Comment: This question definitely needs more focus. You'll need to show us what you've tried so far and what you have problems with. If you've already tried something, feel free to edit your question to include some code.

Comment: see also https://javascript.info/array-methods#shuffle-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've explained it yourself. You just had to search for the commands online...

```js
const input = 'abc';
const output = input
  .split('') // make it into strings
  .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()) // shuffle
  .join(''); // convert to a string
```

Not sure if you need the result to be an array of a single item, or just a string :|

Also, keep in mind the output **might** be the same as the input! If you don't want this - call the function as many times as needed in order to get a different output.

---

**Edit**: as @[PA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30447/pa) mentioned, using the above-mentioned way to sort arrays is not a great idea. Even though it might currently work, it can lead to bad results. The reason is that the sort algorithm *might* (not sure) need static values for each item. Theoretically, that might be a problem. Therefore something like this can be used:

```js
const input = 'abc';
const output = input
  .split('') // make it into strings
  .map((v) => [Math.random(), v]) // convert the array of characters into tuples (pairs)
  // of a random element and the real value
  .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]) // sort, based on the random values
  .map(([rand, value]) => value) // return to list of characters
  .join(''); // convert to a single string
```

This way you set the random value once, then do the shuffling, then remove the random values.

Comment: Never ever shuffle by sorting with a random comparator ! because it breaks the sort internal logic and can lead non random solutions and event to infinite loops. Use a well known algorithm instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c-sharp

Comment: Not sure how that helps in any way with this particular question :) But out of curiosity - how can a JS sort using random can lead to infinite loops?

Comment: well, the internal workings of the sort algorithm is a black box.  A random comparison function is not deterministic. The algorithm assumes that if a>b and b>c then a>c but a random comparator does not honor this assumption, so the algorithm might get lost, confused and it might lead in certain implementations to loop forever or take inusual long times. See https://rufflewind.com/2016-09-16/random-comparator-sort

Comment: "From an engineering perspective, sorting functions are designed to sort things. Abusing it to shuffle an array is kind of just asking for trouble, because you never know if a change in the sorting algorithm down the road might break the “shuffling” algorithm. Worse, the breakage could be subtle, creating biases in the output that might be hard to detect unless the tests rigorously verify the statistics. Moreover, some sorting algorithms can run unusually slow with a random comparator, or take a very long time if the randomness was not in their favor."

Comment: I agree with your point, even thought it's highly theoretical, and having the context of this question, it doesn't matter :D But I'll update my post with another solution ;)

Comment: I've done a little experiment. And each comparison can be evaluated differently because the sort callback is dynamic (obviously :D). Because of that, it's relatively simple to have at least many iterations. And in theory, those iterations might never end. I'll need to do another test to figure out what kind of sorting they use :) Entirely not related to the topic, but still an excellent brain game, thanks!

Comment: afaik javascript sort uses QuickSort algorithm