# Given an array of string what is the simplest way to sort them randomly?

Tags: c#, sorting, random, shuffle

What I came up with is:

```
RandomSort()
{
  string[] list = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", ... }
  Random rnd = new Random();
  string[] list2 = list.OrderBy((x) => rnd.NextDouble()).ToArray();
}
```

Is there some other way, maybe using a `Dictionary` or something? Thanks.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/108819/128397), where the best answer is actually not the accepted answer but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-a-string-array-in-c/110570#110570) which has C# code for a Fisher-Yates Shuffle aka Knuth Shuffle implementation.

Comment: I did a search for random sort and it did not show up. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Note that if you are shuffling for the purposes of, say, producing a deck of cards to play online poker, then this is not sufficiently random. "Random" is only pseudo-random; it is an easy exercise to predict the order of all the other cards given a small sample of a pseudo-random shuffled deck. If you need truly unpredictable randomness then use a better randomness algorithm, like the crypto algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That certainly is simple but it's O(n log(n)). You can do better performance-wise by using the [Fisher Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle.