# Generating random numbers from giving numbers in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

User enters numbers to 10 textbox and i sent them to an array. Now i want to generate random numbers from this array. What can i do?

Comment: Do you want to pick random numbers from the aray; or use the array as a "seed" for the random number generator?

Comment: Wait... so you wanted to shuffle the array, not seed the PRNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class Randomizer<T>
{
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();
    private readonly IList<T> _numbers;
    public Randomizer(IList<T> numbers)
    {
        _numbers = numbers;
    }

    public T Next()
    {
        int idx = _random.Next(0, _numbers.Count);
        return _numbers[idx];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var r = new Randomizer<int>(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 });
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     Console.Write(r.Next() + " ");
```

Or do you want to [shuffle the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-a-string-array-in-c)?

**[Edit]**

To shuffle the array, you can use the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle) shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-a-string-array-in-c/110570#110570):

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/110570#110570
public class Shuffler
{
    private Random rnd = new Random();
    public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array)
    {
        int n = array.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            int k = rnd.Next(n);
            n--;
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the interface to be same as the `Randomizer` class above, you can modify it to use the `Shuffler` class:

```
public class Randomizer<T>
{
    private readonly Shuffler _shuffler = new Shuffler();
    private readonly IList<T> _numbers;
    public Randomizer(IList<T> numbers)
    {
        _numbers = new List<T>(numbers);
        _shuffler.Shuffle(_numbers);
    }

    volatile int idx = 0;
    public T Next()
    {
        if (idx >= _numbers.Count)
        {
            _shuffler.Shuffle(_numbers);
            idx = 0;
        }

        return _numbers[idx++];
    }
}
```

Note that the code is **not thread safe**, so some locking should be implemented if `Next` method might be called simultaneously from multiple threads.

Comment: ok, it works but also i want to kick number that randomizer generate from array for not repeating.

Comment: @ActuallyMAB: then you are talking about shuffling the array ([link to an SO answer is at the end of my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-a-string-array-in-c)). Could you clarify what should happen when all array numbers are depleted? Should it reshuffle and restart? Or throw an exception?

Comment: actually i want to not repeating numbers. for example result cant be like this: 5-9-5-12.

Answer (score 1):

[Seed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) the standard [System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts6se2ek.aspx) class with a value from the array? If you need your random numbers to depend on ALL array items, then just XOR them all.

```
public static Random BuildSeededRandom(int[] data)
{
    if ( data == null || data.Length < 1 )
        return new Random();

    int xor = 0;
    foreach ( var i in data )
        xor ^= i;

    return new Random(xor);
}
```