# Displaying random canvas using c# for wp7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, random

I'm creating a quiz game for Windows 7. Each question opens up in a new canvas. How can I randomize the canvas view so that each time a player plays the game he gets random questions?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but looks simple enough. all you need to do is select a random canvas and display it ?

have a look at wordastic for windowsphone. it has a single view and I change displayed data randomly.

Comment: I've downloaded the Wordastic app. And yes, that's what I exactly need. And can we add a previous button, so that when a user clicks it, it would lead them back to the previous question? Help appreciated.

Comment: sure as long as you keep a reference to previous question, you can display it just fine. create a variable called previousQuestion and every time you come to set new question, you set the currentQ to previousQ

Comment: Can you please help me on how to display a random canvas. I'm new to wpf.

Comment: well I have a 3x3 grid but you can use anything. it contains border and textblock elements inside each. depending upon the number of elements I want to display, I set the textblocks or just toggle visibility of border elements.

Comment: can you randomise words ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-a-string-array-in-c-sharp now all you need to do is loop through this random list and assign them to different textblocks in a grid