# Shuffle cards, the dotnet way!!, Is the complexity of algorigthm acceptable?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Using framework's `Random` class I came up with following lazy implementation to shuffle a deck of card.

I estimate worst case complexity of following code as O(N + NlogN). Am I right?

DataStructures

```
enum SuitType
{
    Diamond,
    Heart,
    Spade,
    Club
}

class Card
{
    public SuitType suitType;
    public int value;
    public int randomOrder;
}
```

> 1. I have added a variable randomOrder with each card.
> 2. Then I am using Randome.Next() to get a random number for each card.
> 3. Sort the deck based on this random number.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            List<Card> deck = new List<Card>(52);

            p.InitializeDeck(deck);
            List<Card> shuffledDeck = p.ShuffleDeck(deck).ToList();
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        readonly int RMIN = 1, RMAX = 100;

        //O(N + NlogN)
        private  IEnumerable<Card> ShuffleDeck(List<Card> deck)
        {
            //O(N)
            foreach (var d in deck)
            {
                d.randomOrder = r.Next(RMIN, RMAX);
            }
            //O(NlogN)
            return deck.OrderBy(d => d.randomOrder);
        }

        private  void InitializeDeck(List<Card> deck)
        {
            int suitCounter = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 52; i++)
            {
                deck.Add(new Card
                {
                    suitType = (SuitType)suitCounter,
                    value = i,
                    randomOrder = r.Next(RMIN, RMAX)
                });

                if (i % 13 == 0)
                {
                    suitCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-a-string-array-with-net).

Comment: This seems kind of silly when there is a [simple O(n) shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: [The Danger of Naïveté](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the whole body of the `ShuffleDeck` method with

```
return deck.OrderBy(d => r.Next());
```

This probably doesn't affect the algorithmic complexity, but it makes the method simpler.

#### Update:

My opinion is that thinking in terms of Big-O notation is not relevant here unless you have to shuffle millions of decks and discover that performance is really a problem.

Comment: Awesome, in that case I do not even need another variable `randomOrder` in my data structure.

Comment: @autrevo yes, `randomOrder` can be removed. IMHO it didn't belong there, anyway.

Comment: @autrevo I think your estimation is correct. But please see the update to my answer and see if it makes sense.

Comment: 1 QQ, how the execution happens at runtime, when we rely on `r.next()`

Comment: Does LINQ generates list first & then sorts or it keeps sorting as soon as new random no. is generated from `r.next()`?

Comment: @autrevo I just tested and the `r.Next()` is called N times (where N is the size of the deck), just like in your example. Here's the proof: http://ideone.com/inBdQV

Comment: @autrevo However, I suggest that you visit the links in the comments to your question. The call to `rand` may be O(n), but the sorting is still O(n log n) and there are better options.