# Visual Studio 2010 crashes after pasting simple code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crash, console-application

Start by creating a new console application (VB.NET). Paste the following code in `Sub Main`:

```
Dim AAAAAAAAAAA = BBBBBBB
```

Put the cursor before `Sub Main` and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on the keyboard.

[image]

VS crashes:

[image]

If the number of `A`s or `B`s is less - it won't crash. Same or more - it will. **Why?**

Also, **can anyone else reproduce it?**

I am able to reproduce 100% of the time, on three different workstations, one is Windows 7 x64, another is Windows Server 2012, and also my home PC (Windows 7 x64), where I am getting a slightly different crash screen:

[image]

**Note:** This is not just a curiosity question, I originally got the exception when trying to paste some code from StackOverflow. So it does happen in real scenarios, and sometimes when pasting into a work-in-progress project, in the middle of development (but I was not able to reproduce this scenario).

Comment: Wow, really? Just by pasting it in? (VS 2010, so I can not try to reproduce...)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Paste and delete the blank line, yes. I am shocked. Especially if it's more than just me. The relevance to variable lengths is something I cannot explain.

Comment: Is this the entry point?

Comment: Yeah, `Sub Main` is the entry point. It's a brand new console app.

Comment: I have VS 2010 and added a `Module1` with your code. If i press delete nothing happens (apart from the line that gets deleted).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Don't add any files, don't change windows, it throws the code of Module1 in front of you on creation, so just create a blank console app, paste and delete.

Comment: Okey, I read 2010 as 2012. I've tested and it didn't crash. Hmmm, strange...

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: You mean it does **not** crash in 2012?

Comment: @Neolisk: i cannot reproduce this issue. I have created a blank new console application, the `Module1` gets created, i put the cursor in the empty line before `Sub Main` and press `delete`. The line is deleted.

Comment: Haha.. I mean I _thought_ you had VS 2012 (which is common these days), but I have 2010 as you have.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You pasted the above in `Sub Main` before deleting, right?

Comment: And you are sure there aren't any special chars being pasted?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Yes, I tried pasting into Notepad to get rid of any possible formatting, then copy again and paste into VS 2010. Same effect.

Comment: Which keyboard language are you using? EN?

Comment: @Neolisk Try change the .net version before you create the project and see if that has any effect.

Comment: @Neolisk: yes, of course, i've pasted your line. I have no idea what's cauing your issue, sorry. However, simply don't paste that line and you're safe ;-)

Comment: Does not crash in 2012

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It's not just that line, I've pasted some code from StackOverflow and it crashed in the same way. So I started investigating to produce a reduced test case for the problem. The code was from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/108836/897326), first two lines, so you can try copy/paste those as well, same way, into an empty console app.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Yes, EN (US). Tried .NET 2.0 - same effect.

Comment: @Neolisk Okay.. I still cannot reproduce this error. What makes this even stranger is that you can reproduce this `on two different workstations`. Do the error occur if you add a few line breaks?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Thanks for trying to help so far. If I add line breaks first, then remove all of them, it still crashes. If I use backspace to clear the blank line, it does not crash. However, if I then add a blank line again, using Enter, and use Delete to remove it, it still crashes. I will definitely need to try this at home, I have a PC and a laptop, both armed with VS 2010.

Comment: @Neolisk I'm running win7 and as far as I can see you're running win8. (This might narrow it down a bit.) BTW, you can try to launch VS in "log mode": `In desktop mode, press the Windows key and R at the same time >> type "Devenv.exe /log <log path>.`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: First workstation is Windows 7 x64, second is Windows Server 2012. I have the same problem at home (VS 2010), but a slightly different screen on crash.

Comment: Confirmed: the issue does not happen in VS 2012 and 2013.

Comment: Okay. Did you try to launch VS in "log mode"? Star >> Run >> Devenv.exe /log <log path>. FYI: This is my last post for today, it's midnight, and I'm going to bed :p

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Looks like nothing gets logged after I press the Delete key. So Log file size before and after pressing Delete is the same = 400K.