# How can I select a random value from a list using F#

Tags: random, f#, f#-interactive

I'm new to F# and I'm trying to figure out how to return a random string value from a list/array of strings.

I have a list like this:

```fs
["win8FF40", "win10Chrome45", "win7IE11"]
```

How can I randomly select and return one item from the list above?

Here is my first try:

```fs
let combos = ["win8FF40";"win10Chrome45";"win7IE11"]  

let getrandomitem () =  
  let rnd = System.Random()  
  fun (combos : string[]) -> combos.[rnd.Next(combos.Length)]
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you are mixing `Array`s and F# `List`s (`*type*[]` is a type notation for `Array`).  You could modify it like this to use lists:

```fs
let getrandomitem () =  
  let rnd = System.Random()  
  fun (combos : string list) -> List.nth combos (rnd.Next(combos.Length))
```

That being said, indexing into a `List` is usually a bad idea since it has O(n) performance since an F# list is basically a linked-list.  You would be better off making `combos` into an array if possible like this:

```fs
let combos = [|"win8FF40";"win10Chrome45";"win7IE11"|]
```

Comment: Looks like I was pretty close.  Thanks!  All the other answers were pretty informative - learned a lot more from the answers than I expected.

Answer (score 23):

Both the answers given here by *latkin* and *mydogisbox* are good, but I still want to add a third approach that I sometimes use. This approach isn't faster, but it's more flexible and more composable, and fast enough for small sequences. Depending on your needs, you can use one of higher performance options given here, or you can use the following.

## Single-argument function using Random

Instead of directly enabling you to select a single element, I often define a `shuffleR` function like this:

```
open System

let shuffleR (r : Random) xs = xs |> Seq.sortBy (fun _ -> r.Next())
```

This function has the type `System.Random -> seq<'a> -> seq<'a>`, so it works with any sort of sequence: lists, arrays, collections, and lazily evaluated sequences (although not with infinite sequences).

If you want a single random element from a list, you can still do that:

```
> [1..100] |> shuffleR (Random ()) |> Seq.head;;
val it : int = 85
```

but you can also take, say, three randomly picked elements:

```
> [1..100] |> shuffleR (Random ()) |> Seq.take 3;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [95; 92; 12]
```

## No-argument function

Sometimes, I don't care about having to pass in that `Random` value, so I instead define this alternative version:

```
let shuffleG xs = xs |> Seq.sortBy (fun _ -> Guid.NewGuid())
```

It works in the same way:

```
> [1..100] |> shuffleG |> Seq.head;;
val it : int = 11
> [1..100] |> shuffleG |> Seq.take 3;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [69; 61; 42]
```

Although the purpose of `Guid.NewGuid()` isn't to provide random numbers, it's often random enough for my purposes - random, in the sense of being *unpredictable*.

## Generalised function

Neither `shuffleR` nor `shuffleG` are truly random. Due to the ways `Random` and `Guid.NewGuid()` work, both functions may result in slightly skewed distributions. If this is a concern, you can define an even more general-purpose `shuffle` function:

```
let shuffle next xs = xs |> Seq.sortBy (fun _ -> next())
```

This function has the type `(unit -> 'a) -> seq<'b> -> seq<'b> when 'a : comparison`. It can still be used with `Random`:

```
> let r = Random();;    
val r : Random    
> [1..100] |> shuffle (fun _ -> r.Next()) |> Seq.take 3;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [68; 99; 54]
> [1..100] |> shuffle (fun _ -> r.Next()) |> Seq.take 3;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [99; 63; 11]
```

but you can also use it with some of the cryptographically secure random number generators provided by the Base Class Library:

```
open System.Security.Cryptography
open System.Collections.Generic

let rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider ()
let bytes = Array.zeroCreate<byte> 100
rng.GetBytes bytes

let q = bytes |> Queue
```

FSI:

```
> [1..100] |> shuffle (fun _ -> q.Dequeue()) |> Seq.take 3;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [74; 82; 61]
```

Unfortunately, as you can see from this code, it's quite cumbersome and brittle. You have to know the length of the sequence up front; `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` implements `IDisposable`, so you should make sure to dispose of `rng` after use; and items will be removed from `q` after use, which means it's not reusable.

## Cryptographically random sort or selection

Instead, if you *really* need a cryptographically correct sort or selection, it'd be easier to do it like this:

```
let shuffleCrypto xs =
    let a = xs |> Seq.toArray

    use rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider ()
    let bytes = Array.zeroCreate a.Length
    rng.GetBytes bytes

    Array.zip bytes a |> Array.sortBy fst |> Array.map snd
```

Usage:

```
> [1..100] |> shuffleCrypto |> Array.head;;
val it : int = 37
> [1..100] |> shuffleCrypto |> Array.take 3;;
val it : int [] = [|35; 67; 36|]
```

This isn't something I've ever had to do, though, but I thought I'd include it here for the sake of completeness. While I haven't measured it, it's most likely not the fastest implementation, but it should be cryptographically random.

Comment: You write that
>Neither `shuffleR` nor `shuffleG` are truly random. Due to the ways `Random` and `Guid.NewGuid()` work, both functions may result in slightly skewed distributions.
but according to the [wikipedia page on the Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Comparison_with_other_shuffling_algorithms) the issue may be with the chosen algorithm (specifically relying on implementation details of `Seq.sortBy`). Would you consider noting this in your answer?

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a blog post on exactly this topic a while ago: http://latkin.org/blog/2013/11/16/selecting-a-random-element-from-a-linked-list-3-approaches-in-f/

3 approaches are given there, with discussion of performance and tradeoffs of each.

To summarize:

```
// pro: simple, fast in practice
// con: 2-pass (once to get length, once to select nth element)
let method1 lst (rng : Random)  =
    List.nth lst (rng.Next(List.length lst))

// pro: ~1 pass, list length is not bound by int32
// con: more complex, slower in practice
let method2 lst (rng : Random) =
    let rec step remaining picks top =
        match (remaining, picks) with
        | ([], []) -> failwith "Don't pass empty list"
        //  if only 1 element is picked, this is the result
        | ([], [p]) -> p
        // if multiple elements are picked, select randomly from them
        | ([], ps) -> step ps [] -1
        | (h :: t, ps) ->
            match rng.Next() with
            // if RNG makes new top number, picks list is reset
            | n when n > top -> step t [h] n
            // if RNG ties top number, add current element to picks list
            | n when n = top -> step t (h::ps) top
            // otherwise ignore and move to next element
            | _ -> step t ps top
    step lst [] -1

// pro: exactly 1 pass
// con: more complex, slowest in practice due to tuple allocations
let method3 lst (rng : Random) =
    snd <| List.fold (fun (i, pick) elem ->
               if rng.Next(i) = 0 then (i + 1, elem)
               else (i + 1, pick)
           ) (0, List.head lst) lst
```

**Edit:** I should clarify that above shows a few ways to get a random element from a list, assuming you *must* use a list. If it fits with the rest of your program's design, it is definitely more efficient to take a random element from an array.

Comment: Why not just use the built-in function?

Comment: I don't follow. There is no built-in function to obtain a random list element, hence the question.