# Can this random number generator logic be simplified?

Tags: f#

I am learning F# and would like to know if the following logic to generate random numbers is acceptable.

Could this be written in a more maintainable fashion?
Is this code safe?

```
let hashset = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>()
let mutable continueLooping = true

while (continueLooping) do 
   let value = System.Random().Next(0, 12)
   let success = hashset.Add(value)
   continueLooping <- hashset.Count <> 12
```

**UPDATE**

```
let hashset = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>()
let randomGenerator = System.Random()
let mutable continueLooping = true
let expectedLength = 12

while (continueLooping) do 
   let value = randomGenerator.Next(0, expectedLength)
   let success = hashset.Add(value)
   continueLooping <- hashset.Count <> expectedLength
```

Comment: Isn't this just an inefficient way of creating a set containing `[0..11]`?

Comment: No, because it may contain repeats.

Comment: I wanted unique numbers. Again, I'm just asking for guidance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select a random value from a list using F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312260/how-can-i-select-a-random-value-from-a-list-using-f)

Comment: oops yes - I saw to late - it's indeed a bit strange that you pull 12 random numbers out of `0..11` inside a hashset that will loose any ordering of those

Comment: As outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33316100/126014), create any list, and then shuffle it afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a helper function to perform a Fisher-Yates shuffle.  This shuffle function is pretty generally useful since it will work on any `seq<'a>` so you have plenty of opportunities to reuse it.

```
// shuffle a sequence into random order
let shuffle xs =
    // swap two elements in the supplied array
    let swap i j (array : _[]) =
        let tmp = array.[i]
        array.[i] <- array.[j]
        array.[j] <- tmp
    let rnd = System.Random()
    let xArray = Seq.toArray xs
    let n = Array.length xArray
    for i in [0..(n-2)] do
        let j = rnd.Next(i, n-1)
        swap i j xArray
    xArray |> Seq.ofArray
```

Then just apply it to a list or something using

```
let shuffledList = [0..11] |> shuffle |> Seq.toList
```