# Random and Uniqu number

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of 40 names, a list of 40 picture boxes, I want to show these names randomly and uniquely in picture boxes.

I tried but my effort is worthless. Any help would be appriciated.

```
        Random r = new Random();

        List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1, box.Count).ToList();
        List<int> rndList = new List<int>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int no = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < box.Count; i++)
        {
            no = rnd.Next(0, list.Count);
            rndList.Insert(i, no);
            list.Remove(no);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < box.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly sysrefass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(sysrefass.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources", ((System.Reflection.Assembly)sysrefass));
            box[i].Image = (Image)rm.GetObject(rndList[i].ToString());

        }
```

Comment: You don't actually want random items, what you want to do is shuffle the list of items. There are many examples of that on this site you can use

Answer (score -1):

Just fill `box[]` in ordinal order, for example with

```
box[i].Image = (Image)rm.GetObject(i.ToString());
```

and then use [`OrderBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with random value or `Guid`:

```
var randomizedBox = box.OrderBy(b => rnd.Next).ToArray();
var randomizedBox2 = box.OrderBy(b => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't understand where I have to put 2nd statement you wrote here.

Comment: This is not a [good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm)

Comment: Well you can use it immediately after last loop. Also, you can reuse same variable like `box = box.OrderBy(b => rnd.Next).ToArray();` but it can be unclear because name `box` does not contain extra information about your variable. 
You should put this line after filling box array.

Comment: @dotctor well  Scott not referenced concrete answer about shuffling but the first google link uses the same method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net 
and wow it has good rating because it's short and useful. 

John's article is good, but my solution is not bad too I think.