# Load random scenes without repetition using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, random, scene

I want to load scenes randomly without repetition using c#. Any help would do.
Thanks.

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
List<int> list = new List<int>();

void Start()
{
    list.AddRange(array);
}

int GetUniqueRandom(bool RemoveFromTheList)
{
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        if (RemoveFromTheList)
        {
            list.AddRange(array);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1; // never repeat
        }
    }

    int rand = Random.Range(0, 10);
    int value = list[rand];
    list.RemoveAt(rand); return value;
}
```

Comment: You didn't post any code.

Comment: int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
   List<int> list = new List<int>();
   void Start()
    {
        list.AddRange(array);
    }
    int GetUniqueRandom(bool RemoveFromTheList)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
          if (RemoveFromTheList)
           {
                list.AddRange(array);
            }
            else
            {
                return -1; // never repeat 
            }
        }
        int rand = Random.Range(0, 10);
        int value = list[rand];
        list.RemoveAt(rand);
        return value;
    }

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

A nice clean way is to shuffle the array, then put all the elements in a stack. All you need to get a random element is to pop an item off the stack.

You will want to remove the list in the list of fields and replace with this;

```
Stack remainingScenes = new Stack();
```

Remove the content of the Start() method - you don't need it.

In your method to get a new number;

```
if (remainingScenes.Count == 0) {
    int n = array.Length;
        while (n > 1) 
        {
            int k = rng.Next(n--);
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }

        foreach(var element in array) { 
             remainingScenes.Push(element);
        }
}

return remainingScenes.Pop();
```

The shuffle method is [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/6722).

Comment: still not working. do you have simple way to random scenes without repeating until the scenes are all loaded? using array not list.

Comment: What for? I've given you line-by-line edits to make to your code.

Comment: and the problem is, i dont where I will attach or drag this script.

Answer (score 0):

Uhmmm, this looks very straightforward. Judging from your code, you only need a little modification to make it work..

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

int GetUniqueRandom(bool RemoveFromTheList)
{
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        return -1;//nothing in the list so return negative value
    }
    //generate random index from list
    int randIndex = Random.Range(0, list.Count - 1);
    int value = list[rand];
    if(RemoveFromTheList)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(randIndex);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: where will i attach this script ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
Stack<int> stack = null;
```

Then initialize like this:

```
var rnd = new Random();
stack = new Stack<int>(array.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
```

Now you just keep getting values from the stack until it is empty:

```
var value = stack.Pop();
```