# Unity 3D Quiz game random questions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i got 10 questions, so when the game starts, example the starting question is "**4 out of 10**" then if the next question is random to **"10 out of 10"** the game ends. what i want is to random the 10 questions:

```
private int idMode;
public Text question;
public Text answerA;
public Text answerB;
public Text answerC;
public Text answerD;
public Text infoAnswer;
public Text stat;
public string[] questions;          
public string[] alternativeA;   
public string[] alternativeB;
public string[] alternativeC;
public string[] alternativeD;
public string[] correct;
private int idQuestion; 
private float points;
private float fact; 
private float average;
private int results;

void Start () {
    idMode = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("idMode");
    idQuestion = 0;
    fact = questions.Length;
    question.text = questions [idQuestion];
    answerA.text = alternativeA [idQuestion];
    answerB.text = alternativeB [idQuestion];
    answerC.text = alternativeC [idQuestion];
    answerD.text = alternativeD [idQuestion];
    infoAnswer.text = (idQuestion + 1).ToString() + " of " + fact.ToString () + "";
}
public void answer(string alternative)
{
    if (alternative == "A") {

        if (alternativeA [idQuestion] == correct [idQuestion]) {

            points += 1;

        } else {

        }
    }
    if (alternative == "B") {

        if (alternativeB [idQuestion] == correct [idQuestion]) {

            points += 1;
        } else {
    }

}
    if (alternative == "C") {
        if (alternativeC [idQuestion] == correct [idQuestion]) {
            points += 1;
        } else {
    }
}

    if (alternative == "D") {
        if (alternativeD [idQuestion] == correct [idQuestion]) {
            points += 1;
        } else {
    }
}
    nextQuestion ();
} 
void nextQuestion()
{
    idQuestion += Random.Range(0,10);
    if(idQuestion <= (fact-1))
    {
        question.text = questions [idQuestion];
        answerA.text = alternativeA [idQuestion];
        answerB.text = alternativeB [idQuestion];
        answerC.text = alternativeC [idQuestion];
        answerD.text = alternativeD [idQuestion];
        stat.text = " Correct: " + points.ToString () + "";
        infoAnswer.text =  (idQuestion + 1).ToString() + " of " + fact.ToString () + "";
    }
    else
    {
        average = 10 * (points / fact);
        results = Mathf.RoundToInt (average);
        if (results > PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("results" + idMode.ToString ())) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("results" + idMode.ToString (), results);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("points" + idMode.ToString (), (int)points);
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("resultsTemp" + idMode.ToString (), results);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("pointsTemp" + idMode.ToString (), (int)points);
        Application.LoadLevel("results");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your data structure, make a class that represents the question and the possible answers so you have one array instead of 6.

Once you do that before you start asking questions [shuffle the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/80274) then just go through the list in the new randomized order.

```
[Serializeable] 
public class Question
{
    public string Text;
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string C;
    public string D;
    public string CorrectChoice; //Holds "A", "B", "C", or "D"
}

public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T> (this T[] array)
    {
        int n = array.Length;
        while (n > 1) 
        {
            int k = Random.Range(0, n--);
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then change your code to

```
private int idMode;
public Text question;
public Text answerA;
public Text answerB;
public Text answerC;
public Text answerD;
public Text infoAnswer;
public Text stat;
public Question[] questions;
private int idQuestion; 
private float points;
private float fact; 
private float average;
private int results;

void Start () {
    idMode = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("idMode");
    idQuestion = 0;
    fact = questions.Length;
    questions.Shuffle();
    question.text = questions[idQuestion].Text;
    answerA.text = questions[idQuestion].A;
    answerB.text = questions[idQuestion].B;
    answerC.text = questions[idQuestion].C;
    answerD.text = questions[idQuestion].D;
    infoAnswer.text = (idQuestion + 1).ToString() + " of " + fact.ToString () + "";
}
public void answer(string alternative)
{
    if (alternative == questions[idQuestion].CorrectChoice) 
    {
        points += 1;
    }

    nextQuestion ();
} 
void nextQuestion()
{
    idQuestion += Random.Range(0,10);
    if(idQuestion <= (fact-1))
    {
        question.text = questions[idQuestion].Text;
        answerA.text = questions[idQuestion].A;
        answerB.text = questions[idQuestion].B;
        answerC.text = questions[idQuestion].C;
        answerD.text = questions[idQuestion].D;
        stat.text = " Correct: " + points.ToString () + "";
        infoAnswer.text =  (idQuestion + 1).ToString() + " of " + fact.ToString () + "";
    }
    else
    {
        average = 10 * (points / fact);
        results = Mathf.RoundToInt (average);
        if (results > PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("results" + idMode.ToString ())) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("results" + idMode.ToString (), results);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("points" + idMode.ToString (), (int)points);
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("resultsTemp" + idMode.ToString (), results);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("pointsTemp" + idMode.ToString (), (int)points);
        Application.LoadLevel("results");
    }
}
```

---

If you really don't want to change your data structure this is the other option I mentioned in the comments about creating a mapping array.

```
private int idMode;
public Text question;
public Text answerA;
public Text answerB;
public Text answerC;
public Text answerD;
public Text infoAnswer;
public Text stat;
public string[] questions;          
public string[] alternativeA;   
public string[] alternativeB;
public string[] alternativeC;
public string[] alternativeD;
public string[] correct;
private int idQuestion; 
private float points;
private float fact; 
private float average;
private int results;
private int[] questionMapper;

void Start () {
    idMode = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("idMode");
    idQuestion = 0;
    fact = questions.Length;
    questionMapper = new int[questions.Count];
    for(int i = 0; i < questionMapper.Count; i++)
    {
        questionMapper[i] = i;
    }
    questionMapper.Shuffle();
    question.text = questions [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
    answerA.text = alternativeA [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
    answerB.text = alternativeB [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
    answerC.text = alternativeC [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
    answerD.text = alternativeD [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
    infoAnswer.text = (idQuestion + 1).ToString() + " of " + fact.ToString () + "";
}

//...

void nextQuestion()
{
    idQuestion += Random.Range(0,10);
    if(idQuestion <= (fact-1))
    {
        question.text = questions [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
        answerA.text = alternativeA [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
        answerB.text = alternativeB [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
        answerC.text = alternativeC [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
        answerD.text = alternativeD [questionMapper[idQuestion]];
        stat.text = " Correct: " + points.ToString () + "";
        infoAnswer.text =  (idQuestion + 1).ToString() + " of " + fact.ToString () + "";
    }
    else
    {
        average = 10 * (points / fact);
        results = Mathf.RoundToInt (average);
        if (results > PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("results" + idMode.ToString ())) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("results" + idMode.ToString (), results);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("points" + idMode.ToString (), (int)points);
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("resultsTemp" + idMode.ToString (), results);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("pointsTemp" + idMode.ToString (), (int)points);
        Application.LoadLevel("results");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but do i really have to change my data structure? no other ways?

Comment: There are other ways, but the easiest way to maintain it would be to change the data structure. Another option is create an array of `int`s counting up from 0 called `questionMapper`, and shuffle that. Then you do something like `questions[questionMapper[idQuestion]]`.

Comment: You should try the new data structure though, you should still be able to put the text in to the editor. Also see my latest update, I forgot to put `public` on the members in the `Question` class.

Comment: @Ixion I updated the question again showing how to do the `questionMapper` solution. You will need to still use the `Shuffle()` extension method I showed in the first part.

Comment: thanks very much, but i got error on extension tho "error CS1109: `GameManager.RandomExtensions.Shuffle<T>(this T[])': Extension methods cannot be defined in a nested class" i put your shuffle extension above my code

Comment: It needs to be outside of the `GameManager` class's `{ }`. Just make a new `RandomExtensions.cs` script at put it in the Assets folder, it should still be acessable by your `GameManager` class even if it is not attached to anything.

Comment: i changed "[Serializeable]" to "[System.Serializable]" because i got an error on "[Serializeable]" is it same?

Comment: Scott thank you very much the random is working properly, but even if i pick the correct answer i dont have a score, should i go to the questionMapper?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry my error alright i get it now. thank you tho, you a life saver Scott. hehe

Comment: Instead of [System.Serializeable] you can put `using System;` at the top of the file and just use [Serializeable] it is the same.