# Char in random position

Tags: c#, random

I`m facing with the problem of putting char in random position.

I have a table full of dots and I have to replace 30% of these dots with `*`

[image]

Size: 10x5

I used function `Random`.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

if (rnd.Next() % 10 > 3)
    Console.Write(". ");
else
    Console.Write("* ");
```

Everything is in 2 loops which hold Length and Height of table (10x5).

But it only makes PROBABILITY of 30% to make `*` instead of `.`

[image]

It takes good position but every time I start a program there is different amount of `*`.

It should just have 16 of `*` (17 - if rounded) every time I start the program

How should I suppose to make 30% always instead of probability?

Comment: So you've 50 stars in a table? And, you want to make almost 14 `*` ?

Comment: Don’t re-initialise the random number generator inside the loop. Doing so is an (undiagnosed) error that will destroy the generator’s statistical properties. Instead of random numbers you’ll get non-random (= potentially extremely regular) garbage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 50 dots. calculate `50*30/100`, it becomes 15.

Then generate 15 unique random numbers within range of 0 to 50. those numbers are indexes you have to replace `.` with `*`

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0,50).OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).Take(50*30/100).ToList();
```

If you are working with 2d index, its fairly easy to convert 1d index into 2d index.

```
var i = index % 5;
var j = index / 5;
```

According to what @KonradRudolph said if you don't want to use OrderBy you can check out other ways to shuffle array (or create randomized set) posted here [Best way to randomize an array with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net)

[Here is more efficient way using Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/4767498)  that I suggest you to use instead of using OrderBy

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).ToArray();
RandomExtensions.Shuffle(rng, indexes);
```

Comment: I think you'd want a `ToList()` or similar on the end of what you're assigning to `indexes`, unless you want the random selection to change each time `indexes` is referenced later.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever very true. didn't notice deferred execution

Comment: Don’t use the `OrderBy(x => rng.Next())` trick, it’s invalid code! It violates the function’s preconditions (`OrderBy` requires a valid partial ordering) and may break at any time if the implementation changes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph but this approach is very common, I don't think they change implementation, that would be a breaking change.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Just because the approach is common doesn’t mean you should use it. On the contrary, it makes it *worse* that you’re disseminating bad code on Stack Overflow. And no, changing the implementation would *not* be a breaking change: previously correct code will continue to yield the exact same result.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary And just to throw some authority behind my claim (although this should be completely unnecessary): here’s Eric Lippert, one of the main architects of C#, saying the same thing in clear terms: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/01/31/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-four/

Comment: Thanks for the link and your valuable information. ill keep that in mind. @KonradRudolph

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thank you guys! Noticed these changes as well

Answer (score 2):

Write code that does the following:

1. Declare an array with x * y elements
2. Populate the entire array with .
3. Declare a loop with 0.30 * x * y iterations
4. For each iteration, change a randomly selected element from . to *  (you must keep looking until you find one that isn't already a *)
5. Output the array, x elements per line

Comment: you also have to check if the randomly selected element already is a `*` and retry in that case

Comment: This still suffers the problem of not necessarily having 30% of them different. You need to make sure the one you select to change hasn't already been changed. In theory this might only change one entry.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your array to be just 50 elements and forget about the rectangular shape for now. How would you approach that? Declare X dots and 50-X stars, then randomly order them. Like you would randomly order a 1->50 list of numbers.

Now how to randomly order a list of 1->50 numbers? One simple and intuitive way is imagining shuffling cards. Go through the loop and for each position obtain a random number in 1->50. Swap elements chosen (say for i=1 we got random number 7 => swap elements 1 and 7).

Here, you simply need to map this rectangle to those 50 points, which is trivial enough for 2D.

Answer (score 0):

I would randomly select 30% of the possible positions

```
// create char array
int arrayRows = 5;
int arrayCols = 10;
char[,] arr= new char[arrayRows ,arrayCols];

// populate array with dots
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRows; i++)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < arrayCols; j++)
  {
  arr[i,j] = '.';
  }
}

Random rnd = new Random();

int numberOfPossiblePositions = arrayRows * arrayCols;

int k = 0;
while (k < numberOfPossiblePositions * 0.3) {
 int position = rnd.Next(numberOfPossiblePositions);

 int colIndex = position / 10;
 int rowIndex = position % 10;

 // if the cell already has * try again
 if (arr[rowIndex,colIndex] == '*') {
   continue;
 }

 arr[rowIndex,colIndex] = '*';
 k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that holds x*y/3 starts and the rest are dots. order by random and iterate through it.

This is the array:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => new {Text = "*", Order = rnd.Next() })
     .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, x*y - count)
     .Select(i=>new { Text = ".", Order = rnd.Next() }))
.OrderBy(i => i.Order).Select(i=>i.Text).ToList();
```

And this is the code for iteration:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x = 10;
int y = 5;
int count = x*y/3;
var allPlaces =
            Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => new {Text = "*", Order = rnd.Next() })
                .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, x*y - count)
                .Select(i=>new { Text = ".", Order = rnd.Next() }))
            .OrderBy(i => i.Order).Select(i=>i.Text).ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < x; x++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < y; j++) { Console.Write(allPlaces[i*j + j]); } 
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: This is really bad code — please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902328/char-in-random-position/42902493?noredirect=1#comment72904863_42902493 for an explanation.