# Getting random item from Dictionary? Not random

Tags: c#, dictionary, random

I am running multiple threads on my application and in each thread I need to get a random Dictionary item from the account. Now I know of course once in a while you'll get the same item from a small dictionary, but this dictionary has over a thousand items and I am still getting non-unique results?

What do I mean by that? I mean it'll give random results but usually they repeat

Examples:

```
Picked the random username "aidan913"
Picked the random username "aidan913"
Picked the random username "abbiexox9"
Picked the random username "phelan193"
Picked the random username "pbeters92"
```

So It'll repeat it twice sometimes, but not actually give a fully unique item. Surely there has to be a way to get a unique item at least 9/10 times?

```
public KeyValuePair<int, BotInformation> GetAccount()
{
    var account = new KeyValuePair<int, BotInformation>();

    var rand = new Random();
    var randomlyOrdered = _accounts.OrderBy(i => rand.Next());

    lock (locker)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, BotInformation> entry in randomlyOrdered)
        {
            if (!entry.Value.Usable())
                continue;

            account = entry;
        }
    }

    if (!CoreUtilities.IsDefault(account)) // if it found one, update it?
    {
        using (var databaseConnection = Program.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
        {
            databaseConnection.SetQuery("UPDATE `accounts` SET `last_used` = '" + 
                DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' WHERE `username` = '" + account.Key + "' LIMIT 1");
        }

        account.Value.LastUsed = DateTime.Now;
    }

    return account;
}
```

Comment: you are picking the last `Usable` value from the randomized dictionary. Maybe there are only a few `Usable` among the thousands?

Comment: I think that you are also missing the point that random != unique. You best bet would be to keep a list of used items and ignore if it has been used

Comment: 99% are avalible, isAvalible is basically checking if the last_used is more than an hour ago which they are.

Comment: A sequence of random numbers will necessarily repeat itself. Just because you got heads the first time you flipped a coin, that doesn't mean you're guaranteed to get tails the next time. That said, your code has the obvious defect that you are creating a new `Random` object each time you want to select a random element, so if you try to select a random element too often, you'll definitely get the same element multiple times in a row. See marked duplicate for solution to that.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net for information on how to randomize your collection in a way that ensures against duplicate choices, i.e. by shuffling the data instead of picking a new random element each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem

```
public KeyValuePair<int, BotInformation> GetAccount()
{
    var account = new KeyValuePair<int, BotInformation>();

    var rand = new Random();
```

When you new Random() quickly it will have the same key.
New Random() only **once** and the use it.

```
private var rand = new Random();
public KeyValuePair<int, BotInformation> GetAccount()
{
    var account = new KeyValuePair<int, BotInformation>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this line out of the function:

```
var rand = new Random();
```

And it would be better make the instance of the Random static.
Read about Random class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)