# Prevent code from displaying the same image in random sequence?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script which displays random image from the list every X seconds, but sometimes it shows the same image over the course of hours of gameplay. I was wondering how would I go about making it not show the image that has already been shown during current game session. Here's my code:

```
void Start () {

        // start count
        StartCoroutine(RandomReportEvent());

}
```

xx

```
IEnumerator RandomReportEvent(){


        float wait_time = Random.Range (53.5F, 361.2f); // removed 1879.2f

        // test purposes
        // float wait_time = Random.Range (1.7F, 3.2f);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait_time);
        memeWindow.SetActive (true);

        // get random reports number within range
        float ReportValue = Random.Range (1.2F, 57.8F);

        // round to 2 dp
        ReportValue = Mathf.Round(ReportValue * 100f) / 100f;
        // show random report value in Text
        randomReportValue.text = string.Format ("<color=#FF8400FF>{0}K</color>", ReportValue);

        // Show Random Image from list
        showRandomImage();
    }
```

xx

```
void showRandomImage(){

        // count the amount of images 
        int count = memeImg.Count;

        // randomly select any image from 0 to count number
        int index = Random.Range(0, count);

        // assing an image from our list
        sr.sprite = memeImg[index];


    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you make a list of all images, randomize the order of the list, and then just loop through it. When you reach the end, you can either re-shuffle or just restart the same sequence.

You can find a good way to shuffle a list or array in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/27204)

Answer (score 4):

What about creating a list of the images you have, then select a random image with your `int index = Random.Range(0, count);` from that list, after that you remove that item from the list with `yourImagesList.RemoveAt(index);` so in the next iterations the image is not going to be available. You can update the value of `int count = memeImg.Count;`  with `List<T>.Count` after removing the image from the list. 
Sources:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx 
and 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This seems to be a better solution. Let me try it and I'll get back to it!! Much appreciated!!