# Randomize strings in a list

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, random

```
Dim myRandom As New Random
Dim myList As New List(Of String)(New String() {"A", "B", "C"})
myList.OrderBy(Function(i) myRandom.Next).ToList()
For k As Integer = 0 To 2
    MessageBox.Show(myList.Item(k))
Next
```

When you run the code, you will see that the MessageBoxes show **A,B,C**.

I want MessageBoxes show **B,C,A** or **C,B,A** or **A,C,B** or **A,B,C** or **B,A,C** or **C,A,B** according to randomized result.

Note: Using Linq is a must.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your code doesn't make any changes to myList. A LINQ query ALWAYS generates a new list. You need to assign the result of ToList back to your myList variable, i.e.

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(Function(i) myRandom.Next).ToList()
```