# turn string array into char array randomize

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to shuffle a char array and have a string array that contains words "play" and "game"
and have some buttons in my game like this:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h6Ub.jpg)

and this is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Answers.Length; i++) {
                BtnsCharacter = Answers [i].ToCharArray ();
            }
```

but I need is to make a mess in my buttons arraignment wile converting to char in random in every level. 
like the image bellow for example:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3hmQ.jpg)

How could I do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to randomize an array with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Answers.Length; i++) {

 char[] BtnsCharacter = Answers [i].ToCharArray ();

 char[] shuffled = BtnsCharacter.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Posting only code (especially without comments) helps no one to _understand_ what is happening within the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Symon but system shows me this error: F:\make app\p_amirza\p_amirza\Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(37,37): Error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

Answer (score 0):

The answer not from Symon. From Me.

Anyway you have to reference the LINQ Namespace