# Generate random number where each number occurs a specific number of times

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random

```
string [] sarray={ "Hello", "From", "Tutorials", "Point" };
```

**I want to generate a random list of strings from this array where each element generate five times**

Can anyone help me? In any language... 
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Repeat the list 5 times then shuffle it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to randomize an array with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net). It should be simple enough for you to implement the Fisher-Yates algorithm in whatever languageyou want.

Comment: NIce way of advertising but yeah I like tutorial point. :0