# Array.Exists verses Array.Contains: Why unexpected results?

Tags: c#, arrays

In Visual Studio using C#, I have created a random number in Main so there is only one seed for the method `ShuffleMyNumbersArray` which attempts to fill the array with unique numbers from 1 to 52. When I use `Array.Contains` the results are repeatedly correct. However when I use `Array.Exists` there are number duplications in the array with no apparent pattern. My question is why is this happening? What is it about `Array.Exists` that I do not understand? The only thing I can think of is that it may have something to do with the "Not" comparison `!= num`.See the following code for comparison.

Code that works consistently:

```
public static void ShuffleMyNumbersArray(int[] array, Random rand)
{
    int num = rand.Next(1, 53);
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        if (array.Contains(num))
        {
            num = rand.Next(1, 53);
        }
        else
        {
            array[i] = num;
            i++;
            num = rand.Next(1, 53);
        }
    } while (i < 52);
}
```

Code that produces duplicate numbers in the array:

```
public static void ShuffleMyNumbersArray(int[] array, Random rand)
{
    int num = rand.Next(1, 53);
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        if (Array.Exists(array, element => element != num))
        {
            array[i] = num;
            i++;
            num = rand.Next(1, 53);
        }
        else
        {
            num = rand.Next(1, 53);
        }
    } while (i < 52);
}
```

Comment: You didn't invert the condition correctly. It should be `!Exists(element => element != num)`, or just check `element => element == num` and switch the if branches around. Also note that there are [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net) to shuffle arrays.

Comment: Did @Sweeper's answer fix your problem? If so, someone should submit an answer.

Answer (score 4):

`Array.Exists(array, element => element != num)` means if there is at least one element in the `array` that is not equal to `num`.
the correct condition is `!Array.Exists(array, element => element == num)` which means there is no element in the `array` that equals to `num`