# I have a problem in using Array.Sort when sorting multiple arrays according to one reference array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have four arrays array_1, array_2, array_3, array_4.

array_2,array_3,array_4 shall be sorted according to array_1.

When I just sort array_2 according to array_1 it is working.

```
 Array.Sort(array_1, array_2);
```

But when I try this just array_2 is being sorted (or just the array that is sorted in the first line). array_3 and array_4 remain the same.

```
 Array.Sort(array_1, array_2);
 Array.Sort(array_1, array_3);
 Array.Sort(array_1, array_4);
```

Is there a possibility to sort multiple arrays according to one reference array, at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-7.0#system-array-sort(system-array-system-array) at "Remarks")

> Each key in the keys Array has a corresponding item in the items Array. **When a key is repositioned during the sorting**, the corresponding item in the items Array is similarly repositioned.

The main keyword here is "when", so only when a item of `array_1` is repositioned will it effect the second array, therefor if `array_1` is already sorted, nothing will happen to the second array.

`array_1` gets sorted on the first call to `Array.Sort(array_1, array_2);`

There for either assume that `array_1` is unsorted and use `.Clone()` to create copy of the array, where `Array.Sort` will only sort the copy of the original unsorted array, or manually shuffle it prior to sorting the other arrays.

so instead of

```
Array.Sort(array_1, array_2);
```

use

```
Array.Sort((Array)array_1.Clone(), array_2);
```

See a demo here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/b1XkrQ

or if you can't quarantee it is unsorted, shuffle `array_1` prior to calling sort, here you may find implementation of shuffle
[Best way to randomize an array with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819)